# Getting a string from subprocess.call?

Tags: python, subprocess, javac

I have a program the complies Java files in a directory. What I want to do is create an array associating the file name with its console output. I can make the array but I need to somehow get the console output in string form. This is how I print the output right now:

```
for fn in directoryContents:
    if fn.rfind(".java") != -1:
        subprocess.check_call(['javac', fn])    
        java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(fn)
        className = fn[0: fn.rfind(".java")]
        cmd = ['java',  className]
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
        print ("\n")
```

Comment: Refer to the [subprocess doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). It's very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use subprocess.Popen instead:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
somestr = p.stdout.readline()
```

Comment: use `p.communicate()[0]` to support more than one line of console output.

Answer (score 2):

To get output from a command, you could use [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
import subprocess

console_outputs = {fn: subprocess.check_output(["javac", fn])
                   for fn in directoryContents if fn.endswith('.java')}
```

Comment: The one caveat with this is that check_output will throw an exception if the subprocess returns a non-zero value, since there is no other way to retrieve the return value.

Comment: @Thayne: yes. It is the intent.

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't, simply pointing out that an exception might be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.call` takes an optional argument, stdout (as well as stderr) which you can pass a writable file object. You can <del>either pass it a StringIO which will then store the output into a string, or</del> write it to an actual file, and then read it in if you need to.

Comment: It is incorrect. You can't pass `StringIO` as a `stdout` parameter to `subprocess.call`. It expects an object with a valid `.fileno()` e.g., regular files, pipes (and sockets on Unix).

Comment: I didn't know that. Where is that documented?

Comment: From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html): "valid values are PIPE, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None." (the word 'existing' hints that a mere file-like object such as StringIO won't be accepted but it is still ambiguous). You could [report a documentation issue](http://bugs.python.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess.check_output, which returns the output of the command.